# Efficient logic queries

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to write an efficient MySQL expression to determine if a post is visible to the user.

My outer `visible` expression is attempting to first check if the user is an author, but if not, check if the post is publicly viewable. However, when I check the EXPLAIN, it appears the `v_posts` subquery (the 2nd `CASE` / the 'else') is executing regardless of the result of `v_authors.id IS NOT NULL` (the first `CASE`).

Is there any way to spare MySQL from making the unnecessary `v_posts` table join? I plan on adding additional logic tests over time, and this will be used liberally throughout my application, so I'd like this expression to be as structurally efficient as possible.

```
SELECT (
            SELECT (
                CASE WHEN v_authors.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                WHEN (
                    SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM posts as v_posts
                    WHERE id = example_foreign_table.post_id
                    AND first_public_release <= NOW()
                ) > 0 THEN 1
                ELSE 0 END
            ) as visible
            FROM (SELECT 1) as aux
            # attempt to join this user as an author
            LEFT OUTER JOIN authors as v_authors
                ON v_authors.type = 'user'
                AND v_authors.foreign_id = 123
        ) as visible
FROM (
    SELECT 1270 as post_id
) as example_foreign_table
```

DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pnU3aTk4hEBrReDegfSkjN/0

Comment: The best answers will require enough information to create the tables and populate them with test data.  one of the DB Fiddle sites is the easiest way to share that stuff.

Comment: Any answer to improve optimization for this query may not support your future additional logic tests. You should be more specific about what those additional logic tests may be.

Comment: Also I would comment that if you want to run a complex query like this frequently, it might be a good candidate for caching the information, either persistently or in a cache in RAM. The fastest SQL query is the one you don't have to execute.

Comment: *"first check if the user is an author, but if not, check if the post is publicly viewable."* - i do wonder why not put these conditions in the `where` clause?

Comment: @billkarwin with respect to caching, if there are millions of users and millions of posts it would not be practical to cache visibility for every user post combination. And with respect to additional logic conditions, they would be structurally similar to these, but let's just focus on this case for now. How can I prevent an unnecessary join of the v_posts table when the first condition is satisfied?

Comment: Your question is a moving target, because you won't post the table definitions, or a specific task you want to accomplish. I have deleted my answer. Have a nice day!

Comment: The core question is now and has always been "Is there any way to spare MySQL from making the unnecessary v_posts table join?"

Comment: @Dan, I would call this premature optimization.  Why do you think the join is unnecessary?  It is the job of the optimizer to select an execution path.  Does this query run very slowly?

Comment: Could be premature optimization. I think for some of the future joins/conditions I'm planning (i.e. "if the user is a subscriber and the post is available in early-access to subscribers") 99.9% of the time they will evaluate to false so I'd like to avoid doing the join if one of the higher-probability conditions is already true.